# Google Maps API v3 load fail - is there is any size limit in return map data?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps API v3 in my ASP.Net application.Following information are displayed in the map

1. Points with Image Icon
2. Info windows to display Name, Address 1, Address 2, Address 3, City, State, Postal information
3. Polylines

Map loads perfect if the request has 590 Points with Image Icon, 590 Info windows and 420 Polylines, but the map fails to load if my request exceeds that and I did not get any error response from google as well.

I have been through the following 2 KB and my google map request fall in the range, less than 25 000 map loads per day

https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/mapsSupport

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usagelimits

Could any one suggest or help me to fix this problem?

Comment: without code, we cant :)